# rounding down in TSQL 2005

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, decimal, rounding

Is there a simply way to convert the following Excel formula into TSQL:

```
ROUNDDOWN((table.OrderQty / table.PacksPerCase),0)
```

- table.OrderQty = 9
- table.PacksPerCase = 5

"0" indicate that the result will have zero decimal places

Result = 1.0

- table.OrderQty = 9
- table.PacksPerCase = 4

"0" indicate that the result will have zero decimal places

Result = 2.0

Answer (score 0):

Try using FLOOR :

> The FLOOR function returns the largest integer less than or equal to
>   the specified numeric expression.

Your expression should be:

```
FLOOR(table.OrderQty / table.PacksPerCase)
```

Comment: that was also east.  Thank!

Comment: Oh, one more question:  why does select 9/5 = 1 when it should be 1.8

Comment: @user2984486 Since both numbers are integers, SQL Server uses integer division. If you indicate that you want a floating point division by using (for example) `SELECT 9.0/5`, you'll get 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

[`ROUNDDOWN()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/rounddown-HP005209241.aspx) rounds towards zero for negative numbers.

Since [`FLOOR`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms178531%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) rounds towards negative infinity, the closest equivalent in TSQL I can think of is [`ROUND`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms175003%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) with `function` set to 1;

```
ROUND((table.OrderQty / table.PacksPerCase), 0, 1)
```

If you're only dealing with positive numbers, of course FLOOR will also work well.